# Find low contrast black rectangle edges in Python

Tags: python, opencv, edges

I need to find the location (x and y) of the two edges that make up the rectangle in the images below.

I tried several ways but I didn't get anything robust, which made me come here for help.

[Frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuDsw.png)

[Frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ho8E.png)

[Frame 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DdhP.png)

[Frame 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOlbt.png)

I tried to find the edges using ROI's, to make it easier, but I was not successful :(

Frame 1 and Frame 4 are different. To reconcile the two in a single logic, for me is difficult.

[Borders that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1plc5.png)

Please help me, I need to make this robust.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).